# More efficient way of splitting data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a script for importing old stock into a new system. The new system requires that part number and revision are separate, which is good, don't know who decided that shouldn't be the case with the old system.

I'm finding it to be quite slow whilst I'm testing and it seems to be related to the separation of part number and revision. This is that part of my script

```
CASE 
    WHEN ISNUMERIC(RIGHT([Our_Part_No],1)) = 0 AND 
         LEFT(SUBSTRING([Our_Part_No],1,LEN([Our_Part_No])-1),30) 
             COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT IN (Select PMA_PART_ONLY from ASC_PMA_TBL)
        THEN LEFT(SUBSTRING([Our_Part_No],1,LEN([Our_Part_No])-1),30)
    ELSE LEFT([Our_Part_No],30)
    END As [Part No],
CASE 
    WHEN [Our_Part_No] COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT NOT IN (SELECT PMA_PART_ONLY FROM ASC_PMA_TBL )
    THEN 
        CASE
            WHEN ISNUMERIC(RIGHT([Our_Part_No],1)) = 1 Then ''
            ELSE Upper(RIGHT([Our_Part_No],1))
        END
    ELSE ''
    END As [Rev]
```

I am also validating that the part without the revision is a valid part prior to importing.

Any way of improving the efficiency of separating out the revision from the old data.

EDIT:

Sample Data with `our_part_no` as the source data and `Part No` and `Rev` the output

[image]

EDIT2: Source data for verifying stock parts are correct. `PMA_PART_REV` is `varchar(16)` and `PMA_PART_REV` is `varchar(4)`

[image]

Comment: Can your provide a [mcve]? Or at least some sample data and desired output?

Comment: First you might want to stop using IsNumeric : https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/blogs/time-stop-using-isnumeric/

Comment: @SeanLange I've included a table of some source data and the desired output

Comment: @B.Seberle IsNumeric seems to have some flaws. I don't expect any characters outside of A-Z and 0-9, but it's worth checking for.

Comment: Can you add the `ASC_PMA_TBL` object schema and data sample ?

Comment: @max Does that help?

Comment: I have roughly 9500 lines of stock data, and the destination table has an API table to validate input. My script takes roughly 5 minutes to run, and it seems to be down to the attempt at separating Part and Revision from ```our_part_no``` and verifying that exists in the ```ASC_PMA_TBL``` table

Comment: Is not clear the length of revision: 1 char, 2 char, N char ? Mixed i.e. A8 or 8A ? In the last case how you can know the revision part on 699-227A ? In the case on 1 char and numeric rev how you can distinguish it on value 699-2279 where 9 is the revision ?

Comment: @max The column supports 4 ```char``` due to ERP compatibility, but we only ever have a single letter for the revision, so I can be safe in my check for such

Comment: I found PATINDEX more reliable than IsNumeric : https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/patindex-workbench/

Answer (score 1):

You can write a Table Value function

```
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION fn_Rev 
(   
    @p1 nvarchar(50)
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    SELECT  
        CASE 
            WHEN RIGHT(@P1, 1) NOT LIKE '[0-9]' THEN LEFT(@p1, LEN(@p1) - 1)
            ELSE @P1
        END as Part_Number,
        CASE 
            WHEN RIGHT(@P1, 1) NOT LIKE '[0-9]' THEN UPPER(RIGHT(@P1, 1))
            ELSE NULL
        END as Revision,
        CASE 
            WHEN RIGHT(@P1, 1) NOT LIKE '[0-9]' THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END as HasRevision
)
```

Example

```
DECLARE @Parts AS TABLE (
    Our_Part varchar(50) not null
)

insert into @Parts
VALUES
('699-227A'),
('699-229A'),
('699-298A'),
('7010-0026'),
('7010-0039'),
('7080-0015')


select *
from @Parts AS p CROSS APPLY
    fn_Rev(p.Our_Part) as c
```

Result

```
|-----------|-----------------|------------|-------------|  
| Our_Part  |Part_Number      |Revision    |HasRevision  |  
|-----------|-----------------|------------|-------------|  
|699-227A   |699-227          |A           |1            |  
|699-229A   |699-229          |A           |1            |  
|699-298A   |699-298          |A           |1            |  
|7010-0026  |7010-0026        |NULL        |0            |  
|7010-0039  |7010-0039        |NULL        |0            |  
|7080-0015  |7080-0015        |NULL        |0            |  
|-----------|-----------------|------------|-------------|
```

You can also join(LEFT|RIGHT) the `PMA_PART_REV` to check if they exists

Comment: Thanks @Max. It adds about 1 minute to the script run time but covers me in the event someone uses cyrillic revisions.

Comment: To speed up you can create an [indexed view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/sql/relational-databases/views/create-indexed-views?view=sql-server-ver15) in this case you must recompile the function with `WITH SCHEMABINDING`